# Can't upgrade ubuntu 12.04.2(i'm on 12.04.x lts)

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

One weeks ago, I received 12.04.2 upgrade message from update manager.
But official release was today!
And my kernel version was 3.2.x, and grub was 1.99, etc.(cannot see difference)
But when I input `/cat/issue` in terminal, it says 12.04.2 LTS.

Is there way to fully upgrade Ubuntu, including grub and kernel?

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: If lsb_release -a indicates 12.04.2, you are up-to-date. There's a way to upgrade both kernel and X, but you may want to remain with kernel 3.2 and/or experiment with kernel 3.7/3.8, as kernels 3.5 and 3.6 are EOL. Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Just install updates from the Update Manager, there isn't any other way.

If you need the newer 3.5 kernel, manually install `linux-image-generic-lts-quantal` and `xserver-xorg-lts-quantal`, otherwise, you remain with the original 3.2 kernel and xserver.

PS: `cat /etc/issue` says `Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS \n \l` here.

Comment: I *think* you also need this package to upgrade the X stack if desired: `xserver-xorg-lts-quantal`. See release notes:https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#LTS_Hardware_Enablement_Stack